# Question about forcing verilog netlist signals in simulation

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am using ModelSim to simulate a design with verilog netlist and verilog RTL.

My verilog design hierarchy is like this:
`tb` instantiates `inv_dual_tb`;
`inv_dual_tb` instantiates `GF_INV_8_tb`;

There are several signals in `GF_INV_9_tb` which I am interested in. There is a signal called `c`, (`c` is 2-bit) so I try to force the value in my do file (vsim -do 'force .....'):

```
force \/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/c\[0\] 0 0ns
```

This works fine. But there is an other signal in `GF_INV_9_tb` called `/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\pmul/p` (this is 2-bit), so I tried the command below. But ModelSim keeps complaining. I also attached the error information below.

```
force \/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\\pmul/p\[0\]\  0 0ns
# ** Error: (vish-4008) Object '/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\pmul/p[0]' not found.
```

Note:
Modelsim cannot handle the case I mentioned. But the solution provided by dwikle can handle single bit cases or multiple bit without escaped characters

Comment: Are you attempting to force them from within your Verilog source, or from the ModelSim prompt?

Comment: I am trying to force from a do file. Something like this: vsim -do 'do wave.do; force \/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\pmul/p\[0\]\ 0 0ns; run 80ns'

Comment: @dwikle, I update my question. I fix the previous problem with a single bit wire. I add a \<space>  after the signal name. But now, there is another signal which has two bits. It does not work even after I added \<space>  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the signal name within curly braces, and include a space after the escaped signal name.

```
force {/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\pmul/himul/abcd } 0 0ns
```

Another option, or simply as a way to check the proper TCL syntax, is to apply the force in the GUI and see what is echoed to the transcript window.

Comment: The following does not work for two bit signals. force {/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\pmul/p[0] } 0 0ns

Comment: This does work, but I want to control only one bit at a time. force {/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\pmul/p } 00 0ns

Comment: The problem is the signal is an escaped name, so you need a space after the signal. Though is appears even `{/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\pmul/p [0] }` will not work. If you have the option I would suggest asking Mentor support about this.

Comment: Ok. I will check with them. I don't understand why xilinx generated verilog netlists contain this kind of bus structure. Cadence will flatten everything into single bit which is much easier to manipulate.

Comment: Escaped names are evil. Ideally you would not have those either.

Comment: I tried to use the GUI to force the signal and then record the command. Then something funny happened: # error on action  Signals::Action returned error: 
# sim:/tb/inv_dual_tb/GF_INV_8_tb/\pmul/p [1] not found. 
#  Trace back: 
# function is Signals::Action SetMenuState {{can_viewdec {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup {View Declaration}}} {can_viewmem {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup {View Memory Contents}}}

Comment: {can_goto_driver {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup {Goto Driver}}} {can_copy {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup Copy}} {can_findaction {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup Find...}} {can_sigbreak {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup {Insert Breakpoint}}} {can_togcov {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup {Toggle Coverage}}} {can_force {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup Force...}} {can_noforce {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup NoForce}} {can_clock {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup Clock...}}

Comment: {can_change {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup Change...}} {can_createwave {::Vsimmenu::MenuItemCan .signalspopup_popup {Create Wave...}}}}

Comment: I guess I should change my script to get around the buggy software.